# How to sort the lines based on the max repeatations of first part of a line after splitting?

Tags: python, string, sorting

I am trying to sort the lines based on the max number of repetitions after splitting the line.

Example input.txt

```
a.php
b.php
a.py
c.php
d.php
b.txt
a.txt
```

expected output:

```
a.php
a.txt
a.py
b.php
b.txt
c.php
d.php
```

I want to consider '.' and split the line. Later compare every line which is repeated more times and sort them (irrespective of a second part).

I tried by using the importing collection, itertools but did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code!  We generally fix *your* code, rather than handing you a total solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right: you want files that begin with `a.` first, because they are 3 times in the file etc.. You can use `collections.Counter` for this task:

```
from collections import Counter

txt = '''a.php
b.php
a.py
c.php
d.php
b.txt
a.txt'''

c = Counter(v.split('.')[0] for v in txt.splitlines())
print( *sorted(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda k: -c[k.split('.')[0]]), sep='\n' )
```

Prints:

```
a.php
a.py
a.txt
b.php
b.txt
c.php
d.php
```

---

EDIT: To read/write from file, you can use this script:

```
from collections import Counter
with open ('text.txt', 'r') as txt, open ('file.txt', 'w') as s2:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in txt if '.' in line]
    c = Counter(v.split('.')[0] for v in lines)
    print( *sorted(lines, key=lambda k: -c[k.split('.')[0]]), sep='\n', file=s2 )
```

Comment: I tried similar to this. However, I tried your work again it gave me an error. I updated the question please have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could group your elements using `itertools.groupby` and count the values:

```
data = """
a.php
b.php
a.py
c.php
d.php
b.txt
a.txt
"""

from itertools import groupby

splitted = sorted((line.split(".") for line in data.split("\n") if line), key=lambda x: x[0])

result = []
for key, values in groupby(splitted, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    v = list(map(".".join, values))
    result.append((key, len(v), v))

result = sorted(result, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
output = "\n".join(x for item in result for x in item[2])
print(output)
```

Which yields

```
a.php
a.py
a.txt
b.php
b.txt
c.php
d.php
```